# Why is AssertionError not displayed?

Tags: python

As an experiment, I tried catching a failed assertion.

```
try: assert 1==2
except Exception as e: print e
```

Why is nothing displayed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> try: assert 1==2
... except Exception as e: print type(e)
...
<type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>
```

or

```
>>> try: assert 1==2, "They Are Not Equal!!"
... except Exception as e: print e
...
They Are Not Equal!!
```

as to why: it is calling the `__str__` method of the exception when you call `print`... since you did not put any text there, your text is the empty string... which is what's printed.

Comment: If he wanted to see something he could just reduce it to `assert 1==2` but I think the point is to answer why he sees nothing in this particular case.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I think he did before you edited. My comment was also before. +1 now!